# How to re-route directions if original route is detour by user in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, navigation, maps

We can get the route directions from the route query based on the waypoints. But what if the user ignores the route path, and takes a new route. Do we have any mechanism in wp8, to detect a new route, and re-route the waypoints based on the new path taken till the destination.

Any suggestions or snippet links would be great.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you only query for the route one time. You should actively query for the route with the user's current location.

See how to get the current location using the GeoLocator for WP8.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator

Subscribe to the position changed event to get a notification when the user's position changes. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.positionchanged